# How do you make a single line text entry dialog in wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

How do I make a single line text entry dialog in my application? I tried this:

```
def TextEntry(self, e):
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, 'Enter text', 'Text entry')
        dlg.Destroy()
```

But nothing popped up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `show` the dialog!

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None,"Copy and Paste below","heading","This is my text")
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    text = dlg.GetValue()
    print (text)
else:
    print ("Dialog Cancelled")
dlg.Destroy()
```